# Why are we allowed to see vote counts / click on questions in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit

Today I ran into this answer by @URL in the queue[image]

I know that there's a litany of issues with the audit system, and many can't be resolved, but I'm not sure why things like seeing vote counts (as in the picture, which makes it SUPER obvious that this is an audit) and opening the question are allowed. I don't see why they benefit the reviewer for normal reviews anyways, and they trivialize most audits.

Again, I know I'm not the first to mention any of this, but after seeing this for the umpteenth time, I wanted to hear what the consensus on this is. Is this a SO/SE issue, or a deliberate choice on part of the mods?

Comment: As long as you spent a minute thinking if this review is one way or the other, the audit system works just fine. (Okay, just fine is a bit stretching it, but you get the gist: you're not roboreviewing.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I literally immediately hit the vote count, and then laughed.

Comment: Link to the review audit in question: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1307344

Comment: A related post on [meta.se]: [Viewing vote counts while reviewing immediately unmasks review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311570).

Comment: I believe at one time falsifying the vote counts was done for at least some of the review queues, e.g. First Posts.  I found that more reprehensible than exposing the true vote tallies.